# Used .prop() to create a Select All checkbox but don't want the checkbox removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I created a select all checkbox to select and deselect my list.
Everything works great but when I remove the list it also removes the select all checkbox.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
         <div class="item-list">
                <H2>Shopping List</H2>              
                <ul class="check-list">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"/>Select All</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".add-btn").click(function (){
        var addItem = $('#item-add').val();
        $(".check-list").append('<li ><input type="checkbox" class="check-box">' + addItem + '</li>');
    });

    $('#select-all').change(function(){
        $('.check-box').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $(".rem-btn").click(function(){
        $(".check-list input:checked").parent().remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: The select-all checkbox should be placed outside the check-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude `select-all` checkbox when you want to perform the remove operation. [`$.fn.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) can be used to exclude the checkbox from `$(".check-list input:checked")` elements.

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

*use*

```
$(".check-list input:checked").not('#select-all').parent().remove();
```

OR, [`:not` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) can also be used

> Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

```
$(".check-list input:checked:not(#select-all)").parent().remove();
```

Comment: wow it's that easy huh?!?! lol... thanks so much for that it worked like a charm @satpal!!!

Comment: Thanks everyone! You guys are awesome. I hope one day I will be able to help answer other member's questions.

Answer (score 2):

You remove everything from the `check-list` where your `select-all` checkbox also resides. While Satpals solution should work, I think it's semantically better to have the Select-All checkbox placed outside the check-list.

```
    <div class="item-list">
            <H2>Shopping List</H2>              
            <input type="checkbox" id="select-all"/> <label for="select-all">Select All</label>
            <ul class="check-list"></ul>
    </div>
```

You should not need any script changes and there is no need to complicate the selector with exclusions for such a basic task.

Comment: I agree and endorse the solution is better.